# WebAPI no HTTP resource found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

So i have setup an ASP.NET WebAPI app and whenever i try to call the API i get this message:

```
<Error>
  <Message>
    No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI    
   'http://localhost:62834/api/PiDBTest'.
  </Message>
  <MessageDetail>
    No type was found that matches the controller named 'PiDBTest'.
  </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

I have tried a few different urls to get to call the API but still cant get anywhere with it.
I have been using the following url to call the API

```
http://localhost:62834/api/PiDBTest
```

Can't seem to see why I'm not getting any success from the call?

Below is the code for the API controller and the RouteConfig

PiDBTest:

```
public class PiDBTest : ApiController
{
    private pidbEntities db = new pidbEntities();

    // GET: api/PiDBTest
    public IQueryable<PiData> GetPiDatas()
    {
        return db.PiDatas;
    }
}
```

RouteConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With attribute routing enabled, this will work.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/PiDBTest")]
public class PiDBTest : ApiController
{
    private pidbEntities db = new pidbEntities();

    // GET: api/PiDBTest
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IQueryable<PiData> GetPiDatas()
    {
        return db.PiDatas;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still produces the same error. I did previously try `[HttpGet]` after reading previous answers.  Even when i try it without the `[RoutePrefix("api/PiDBTest")]`

Comment: Are you sure the routes are being registered.Check to make sure the `WebApiConfig.Register` is being called on start up.

Comment: I stuck a breakpoint in at the line containing `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(.....` and it hits it when i load up.

Answer (score 1):

Please try change your API class as follows,

```
    public class PiDBTestController : ApiController
    {
        private pidbEntities db = new pidbEntities();

        // GET: api/PiDBTest
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public IQueryable<PiData> GetPiDatas()
        {
            return db.PiDatas;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add [HttpGet] on top of your Method 
    public IQueryable GetPiDatas()

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the controller class name didn't include the word "Controller" in it. I changed the class name from "Vendor" to "VendorController"  then it started working.